# Why do we not see silicon in a structure like graphite?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, allotropes

Silicon exists in a structure similar to diamond, with 4 silicon atoms bonded to each other in a tetrahedron. 
Why do we not see it exist in a structure like graphite?

Is it even possible to get silicon to exist like this? If so could we make graphene but with silicon atoms? 
Not sure why you would, since I understand carbon graphene will still be cheaper. But I would just like to know.

Comment: An answer is this: http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1997-08/866552381.Ch.r.html.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible, and it's already been done! The compound is called [Silicene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicene).

[image: An STM image of silicene, the silicon analog to graphene]

However, silicene generally isn't perfectly flat. (Then again, as  Karl Ratzsch points out in the comments, graphene isn't perfectly flat either). The Wikipedia article notes that it usually takes a puckered shape.

I don't know the reasons for the puckered shape, but I recall being quite surprised that silicene could be synthesized at all. The reason why is that I was taught in high school that silicon very rarely forms double bonds due to its large size. For a visualization, please refer to the absolutely awful image below (if anyone could provide an actual graphic I'd be grateful).
[image]

The black atoms on the left are carbon. The $p$ orbitals overlap to a significant degree, which means that pi-bonds can easily form. The green atoms to the right are silicon. You can see that, because of the larger atomic radius, the p-orbitals don't overlap as much, meaning that double bonds are generally not favorable in silicon. This explains why compounds like [silenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silenes) are relatively unstable.

Pi systems are crucial to the chemistry of carbon--they allow carbon to form multiple bonds, flat rings (like in graphene), and generally be stable in a lot of configurations. The lack of pi-bonding in silicon is sometimes given as a rationalization for why silicon-based lifeforms can't exist, and explains why it's so hard to get silicon into the flat sheets that form silicene.

Comment: Graphene is not flat, either. Cannot be, because only 3D crystallites have perfect long-range order. Landau-Peierls instability this is called.

Comment: @Karl I've just asked [Are all stable 2D Xenes and binaries buckled?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/123524/16035)