# Can other group IV elements form graphene analogs with interesting properties?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, allotropes, carbon-family

Graphene has gathered quite a bit of press due to its unique physical properties which hold enormous promise in a wide range of applications from semiconductors to high strength materials. Given that carbon is similar to other Group IV element chemically, I wonder if there are graphene analogs of other Group IV elements such as silicon, tin or lead and what fascinating properties and useful applications they may hold.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/123524/are-all-stable-xenes-graphene-like-2d-honeycomb-sheets-buckled

Comment: Be careful with tagging, the ones you used, were all wrong. That led to zero links in "related" column.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34971/why-do-we-not-see-silicon-in-a-structure-like-graphite